# How to Check if Two Things Are True

Tags: c#, game-development

I am new to programming. Currently, I am trying to make something simple so I am recreating the classic game Pong to learn. However, I have run into this problem. The player controller is working just fine but when pressing W and S I do not want the player to move. Please help!

```
 if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) & Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S){
        player_one.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    }
```

Comment: The and logic operator is `&&` not `&`

Comment: `&&` not `&`. They do different things.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#logical-and-operator

Comment: When writing && I get an error saying "Invalid expression term '&&'"

Comment: Aside from the wrong operator (`&&` is correct), you messed up the parantheses in your `if` expression... that's why the compiler does not understand the "expression term"...

Comment: @sammieeeee " I get an error saying "Invalid expression term '&&'"" ...that's because you have a `)` in the wrong place. You're closing your `if` statement too early. `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))` - the last `)` here is the end of the `if`. That needs to go to the end of the line just before the `{` so that everything is part of the `if`. Your IDE should be able to show you which opening and closing brackets are paired with each other...pay closer attention to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logical operators aren't like you have used in your decision statement. You want the `&&` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#logical-and-operator).

This:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) & Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S){
    player_one.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
}
```

Should be like this:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
    player_one.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
}
```

In yours you closed the decision parenthesis before including the second condition.

Comment: The operator was not the problem, the parenthesis were. The difference between `&` and `&&` is that `&` will evaluate the right side even if the left side evaluates to `false`, whereas the `&&` is a "short-circuiting" operator and will ignore the right side if it's evaluation will not change the result (i.e. the left side is `false`).